# How to raise an event in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm a little confused about raising an event in Objective-C,

I came from C# (.NET) environment and I would like to learn Objective-c and Cocoa programming.

So here's my question:

I have a little application with a NSTextField that I want to use to listen to an event.

What I want to do : When I double click within this control, it raise an event and pop up ex: an NSAlert that displays "Double clicked".

So how can I do that, I'am a visual person so I need some code exemple to show how it's work; Like what should I put within the .h class and within the .m class.

Thanks in advance,

Alex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you want to do this in a text field, but here is how to do it:

You need to use a subclass that overrides click behavior for double clicks. The header file would look like this:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface ClassName : NSTextField {
    //Any new instance variables here
}
//Any new methods here
@end
```

and the implementation file would look like this:

```
#import "ClassName.h"
@implementation ClassName
- (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)event {
//You can also do this with mouseDown:, depending on when you prefer to handle the event
    if([event clickCount] == 2) {
        //Handle double click here
    } else [super mouseUp:event]; //or pass to parent implementation
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i'm not able to bind this event to the text field... do I need to do something else or it's will override the default behavior and will call the code automatically? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean you're not able to bind it to the text field? If you mean that the event isn't actually on the text field, then you should change the superclass. Just change the class in Interface Builder or change the class you instantiate in your code, and the override should happen automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You need to read up on the [Cocoa Fundamentals and the target/action mechanism](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html). An NSControl (like its NSButton subclass) has a target to which it sends an action with itself as the sender. Not all controls support -doubleAction, but some do.

NSButton/NSButtonCell does not support a double action, so you would need to do some subclassing and override the mouse methods. NSEvent (which is passed into mouse methods) can be queried for its click count to distinguish double-clicks from singles.

Just for the record, it's usually click-and-hold that produces a context menu on OS X and this capability is announced through a down-facing arrow somewhere on the right of the button face. Few people will actually know a menu is there for double-clicking and it's hard to represent this with a symbol on the button face. Consider a click-and-hold trigger for your button's context menu.